# php regex preg_match

Tags: php, regex

what's the regex to match a string containing *at least* 3 hashes used to delimit words?

Matches:

```
the-rain-in-spain
the-rain-in-spain-is-falling-on-the-plain
```

Does not match:

```
the-rain-in
the---in
```

Comment: are you tried doing something yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
\w+(-\w+){3,}
```

`\w` is similar to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

`\w+` matches 1 to many character

`{3,}` is a quantifier that matches preceding group 3 to many times

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about php but this is working for me

```
//string strtmp = "the-rain-in";
//string strtmp = "the-rain-in-spain";
  string strtmp = "the-rain-in-spain-is-falling-on-the-plain";
//string strtmp = "the---in";
  Match matchdec = Regex.Match(strtmp, @"\w+(-\w+){3,}", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);                    
   if (matchdec.Success)
       {
           //your code
       }
```

Hope this helps